# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I want to perform code classification based on sequences of AST. The following table consists of labels and sequences, where the sequences are obtained from the **ast2seq function**. The function converts column **codes** values into sequences of AST, where the column **codes** values consist of Python codes. The labels are obtained by converting column **authors** values using keras.to_categorical, where the column **authors**  consist of programmer names.

|  | labels | sequences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | [ 6. 68. 86. 59. 87. 87. 87. 87. 61. 41. 102. 101. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 74. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 74. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 74. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 74. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 74. 46. 24. 15. 15. 15. 68. 61. 67. 68. 61. 2. 15. 68. 61. 67. 68. 61. 2. 15. 68. 61. 67. 68. 61. 33. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 56. 40. 89. 68. 61. 51. 68. 61. 61. 87. 40. 68. 61. 46. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 56. 40. 89. 68. 61. 51. 68. 61. 61. 87. 40. 68. 61. 46. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 56. 40. 89. 68. 61. 51. 68. 61. 61. 87. 40. 68. 61. 81. 35. 22. 68. 61. 87. 35. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61.] |
| 1 | 2 | [ 49. 100. 100. 49. 100. 100. 100. 6. 92. 68. 86. 68. 86. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 22. 10. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 61. 6. 92. 68. 86. 68. 86. 86. 92. 59. 61. 95. 94. 74. 61. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 6. 92. 68. 86. 68. 86. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 22. 10. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 61. 46. 24. 68. 61. 44. 68. 61. 6. 68. 86. 68. 61. 35. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 92. 15. 68. 61. 2. 68. 61. 68. 61. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 6. 92. 68. 86. 68. 86. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 46. 24. 68. 61. 44. 68. 61. 6. 68. 86. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 92. 15. 68. 61. 2. 68. 61. 68. 61. 61. 35. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 56. 40. 68. 61. 87.] |
| 2 | 3 | [ 48. 100. 6. 68. 86. 22. 10. 10. 68. 61. 61. 61. 6. 68. 86. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 87. 87. 6. 68. 86. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 87. 6. 68. 86. 89. 68. 61. 84. 95. 94. 74. 61. 39. 68. 86. 68. 61. 6. 92. 68. 86. 68. 86. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 22. 10. 68. 61. 61. 6. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 15. 68. 61. 88. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61.] |
| 3 | 1 | [ 49. 100. 41. 102. 101. 81. 24. 68. 61. 33. 87. 41. 102. 101. 81. 24. 68. 61. 33. 87. 41. 102. 101. 101. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 41. 102. 101. 101. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 41. 102. 101. 101. 46. 19. 75. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 46. 19. 3. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 28. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 27. 41. 102. 101. 101. 46. 19. 3. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 46. 19. 75. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 22. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 6. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 86. 87. 28. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 27. 6. 68. 86. 29. 87. 87. 87. 87. 68. 61. 68. 61. 68. 61. 68. 61. 96. 69. 6. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61. 46. 24. 68. 61. 33. 74. 20. 6. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 58. 102. 87. 39. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 6. 68. 86. 22. 10. 22. 68. 61. 61. 35. 22. 89. 68. 61. 51. 89. 68. 61. 51. 74. 61. 61. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61. 58. 102. 101. 22. 68. 61. 68. 61. 89. 68. 61. 84. 74. 61. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 22. 10. 87. 61. 60. 89. 68. 61. 51. 68. 61. 61. 105. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61. 74.] |
| 4 | 3 | [ 6. 68. 86. 22. 68. 61. 22. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 15. 74. 31. 68. 61. 35. 22. 68. 61. 15. 74. 31. 15. 74. 88. 68. 61.] |

The Python code to get X and Y are listed below:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import inspect
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Bidirectional, Dense, Dropout, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np

global class_id
ast_classes = [name for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(ast) if inspect.isclass(cls) and issubclass(cls, ast.AST)]
id_ = defaultdict(lambda: len(id_))
class_id = {x:id_[x]+1 for x in ast_classes}

def ast2seq(tree, list_seq=None):
    global class_id
    if list_seq==None:
        list_seq = list()
    else:
        list_seq.append(class_id[tree.__class__.__name__])
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(tree):
        ast2seq(child, list_seq)
    return np.asarray(list_seq).astype(np.float32)

df = pd.read_csv(r'python_code.csv')
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(df['authors'])
y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)

df['ast_'] = df['codes'].apply(lambda x:ast.parse(x))
df['seq'] = df['ast_'].apply(lambda x: ast2seq(x,None))
ast_sequences = df['seq'].values

maxLength = max(map(len, ast_sequences))
x = pad_sequences(ast_sequences, maxlen=maxLength, dtype='float32')
```

The deep learning model:

```
# Define the maximum length of the AST sequence
max_sequence_length = maxLength

# Define the input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(max_sequence_length,))

# Define the embedding layer
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=128)
embedded_input = embedding_layer(input_layer)

# Define the BiLSTM layer
bilstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
bilstm_output = bilstm_layer(embedded_input)

# Add a dropout layer to prevent overfitting
dropout_layer = Dropout(0.2)
bilstm_output_dropout = dropout_layer(bilstm_output)

# Define the output layer
output_layer = Dense(4, activation='relu')(bilstm_output_dropout)

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Train the model on a dataset of AST sequences and corresponding labels
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

However, when I tried to execute the code, I got the following error:

```
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\proj\proj1.py", line 67, in <module>
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1184, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 885, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 950, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3040, in __call__
    filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1964, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 596, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [5,383,4] 
vs. [5,4]
         [[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at d:\proj\proj1.py:67) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5679]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

It is caused by the incompatible shape between X and Y, where X is 3dim and Y is 2dim. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).